# Align shape to vector using Dgame framework and D language

Tags: graphics, 2d, coordinates, d, 2d-games

I've been using Dgame framework for simple simulations.

I need moving object to be aligned to their velocity vectors.

How is it possible to do that using Dgame?

I see that shape object has setRotation and setRotationCenter. Not sure how to use these to achieve the effect. I realize that default is rotation around origin. This causes objects to drift over time.

Sample code

```
struct GameObject {
Point **position;
// array of pointers to object points
Point *acceleration;
Point *velocity;
double max_speed;
double max_force;
}

shape = new Shape(Geometry.Quads,
Vertex(object.position[0].x, object.position[0].y),
Vertex(object.position[1].x, object.position[1].y),
Vertex(object.position[2].x, object.position[2].y),
Vertex(object.position[3].x, object.position[3].y))

// rotate shape to face velocity here
shape.move(object.velocity.x, object.velocity.y);
```

Comment: So is this what you want to do? http://i.webfreak.org/DE8632

Comment: @WebFreak001 that is what i'm trying to do

Comment: Im guessing just rotation and no position?

Comment: @WebFreak001 yes just rotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using `atan2`. Depending on the orientation of the texture you might need to change the values a bit or add 90/-90 degrees.

For textures that face up:

```
rotation = atan2(-velocity.x, velocity.y);
```

For textures that face right:

```
rotation = atan2(-velocity.y, -velocity.x);
```

You might need to convert the result from radians to degrees or the other way around.